# Excel VBA: Vlookup function returns type mismatch error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm getting a type mismatch error while running this code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Lastrow1 As Long
Dim val As Variant

Lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Sheet1")
  Lastrow1 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For I = 1 To Lastrow1
    If (.Cells(I, "A") <> "") Then
      **val = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Weekday(I, "A"), day_name, 2, 0)**
      Cells(I, "B") = val
    End If
  Next I
End With

End Sub
```

Here is the table array `day_name` with the following values:

```
1 Sunday
2 Monday
3 Tuesday
4 Wednesday
5 Thursday
6 Friday
7 Saturday
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to avoid this error?

Comment: There are other options you should consider.

You could do it simply with formulas and/or formatting
In the VBA function, instead of the VLOOKUP, you could more simply return the day of the week as a string using

    Format(myCell, "dddd")

Another thing you need to consider is that when your routine writes the result, that will also trigger the event.  You may want to either check the Target, or disable events (and then re-enable them after), or both.

Comment: See my edited response to demonstrate a different way of doing the event code

Answer (score 1):

Weekday() is for getting the weekday from a date value.

So you should use `Weekday(.Range("A" & I))` to get the weekday from the value of the cell.

Comment: HI..Thanks for your response. I have tried this but getting run time error '1004'- Method of object_worksheet failed. Please help me on this

Comment: edited. because that code is wthin the `With` block...so should be `.Range`

Comment: if this helped please consider setting my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, hard to say, but maybe you want

```
Weekday(Cells(I, "A"))
```

in the function

**EDIT:** *showing a somewhat different approach*

If I wanted to have the cell adjacent to a cell in column A, contain either the day of the week in text form or a blank, I would write the event macro something like what I have below.  There might be some changes needed depending on how the data gets into the cells.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rRangeToCheck As Range
    Dim C As Range

Set rRangeToCheck = Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(1)
If Not Intersect(rRangeToCheck, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each C In Intersect(rRangeToCheck, Target)
        If IsDate(C) Then
            C.Offset(0, 1) = Format(C, "dddd")
        Else
            C.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next C
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Now the above will work if data is entered manually into the cells.  But if the cell contents is the result of a formula, then target would be the cell containing the formula precedent, or even on a different worksheet.  Those would require a somewhat different approach.

Comment: Hi, Its looking much simple and efficient ! Thank you. But i got runtime error 1004- method "intersect of object 'global' failed while executing this code. Can you please help me

Comment: Post a copy of your workbook at some public site, and post a link here.

Comment: There is one issue with this approach. Actually i am using column B values to make a pivot table. So if i custom format the column B cell as 'dddd',then in the pivot table each days will repeat. Becuase its taking the non formatted value (date) to build the table instead of days.:(

Comment: @user3834451 I don't know what you mean by "this approach".  What approach?  Your requirements are now unclear.  It seemed as if what you wanted was to have the text string for a weekday in column B, which is exactly what the macro I provided accomplishes.  If you want something else, you will need to be specific.